# Node Groups stay 'global' in isolated materials

Tags: materials, node-editor

I wanted to trick the system, but in the end I tricked myself, so seeking your help.
I created a pencil object and assigned three materials to three different vertex groups: for a lead, a wooden part and a cover. Then, I made a separate material to control a color of both lead and cover materials (since I want them to match) via a node group and assigned its node group in lead and body color inputs like this:

[image]

Now, after cloning a pencil object I am trying to isolate the materials, but facing a problem that the node group persists, and instead of staying local under Pencil_ColorControl.XXX for each pencil it is still using a global node group somehow, therefore changing lead colors of all pencils.

How should I properly isolate node groups when cloning objects like this? Thanks in advance.